# org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.KotlinIdeaResolutionException Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Code analysis failed with exception: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.caches.resolve.KotlinIdeaResolutionException: Kotlin resolution encountered a problem while analyzing KtNameReferenceExpression

I am using Android Studio Version 4.2.1 and my current Kotlin Version is 202-1.5.10-release-894-AS8194.7 in this I am facing this issue and it does not getting resolved. I have tried many methods but did not find any solution of this issue.

[Error Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usN9V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In my situation, this happened due to the change of dependency versions to earlier ones. From these:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

to these:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
```